# angular2 router with parameters error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

this might be a duplicate, but I could not find the answer.

When I try to navigate to router with params, I get the following error: `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'order/24'`.

My router config is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pm', component: PmComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'orderlist', component: OrderlistComponent},
      {path: 'new-order', component: NewOrderComponent},
      {path: 'order/:id', component: OrderComponent},
      {path: '**', component: PmDefaultComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

in the `new-order` component I try to navigate to `order/:id`:

```
this.router.navigate(['order/', this.orderId]);
```

I have already tried

```
this.router.navigate(['/order/', this.orderId]);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the CLI?

Comment: yes, I have tried this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you defined `path: 'pm', component: ..`, so all children of this route must start with `pm`. Try to navigate to route like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/pm/order', this.orderId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
this.router.navigate(['./order', this.orderId],{
 relativeTo: this.route
});
```

Where `this.route` is an injected `ActivatedRoute` instance. Or you could go with the absolut path option with `this.router.navigate(['/pm/order', this.orderId])`.

- `../` means that you go one level up in the route tree
- `./` means sybling
- `/` means absolut path, `this.router.navigate(['/order', this.orderId]);` would be `root/order/:id` for example

Comment: I have tried `../` and `./`, without success: `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'order/26'`